# Use cycle for in sympy.solve

Tags: python, sympy

I have a this code:

```
sol = sp.solve(eqs, [p[0], p[1], p[2], p[3], lamda], dict=True)
```

`p[0], p[1],...` are variables for any Matrix p in sympy.

My question is: How can I use a cycle `for` instead to type each variable `p[0], p[1],...` etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a range of values (0-3 in your example) you can use the slice notation and `*` to unpack the values:

`sol = sp.solve(eqs, [*p[0:4], lamda], dict=True)`

Not a for loop, but avoids typing out a lot of values.